# Spliting columns with different number of rows including titles

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got data frame like below

```
ID  age type_location          value_1  value_2    
1   83  country:province:city  X:A:J    X:A:I
2   15  country:city           X:K      X:J
3   2   country:province:city  Y:B:I    Y:B:I
4   12  country:city           X:L      Z:K
5   2   country:city           Y:J      X:J
6   2   country:province:city  Y:A:M    Y:B:I
7   18  country:province:city  X:B:J    X:A:L
8   85  country:province:city  X:A:I    Y:B:M
```

To describe it: there is third column (type_location) in which records contain strings separated by ":", at different lengths and this is the name of value in fourth and fifth columns.

As a result, I need to obtain the data.frame as such:

```
ID  age value_1_country value_1_province value_1_city value_2_country value_2_province value_2_city
1   83  X               A                J            X               A                I
2   15  X               'NA'             K            X               'NA'             J
3   2   Y               B                I            Y               B                I
4   12  X               'NA'             L            Z               'NA'             K
5   2   Y               'NA'             J            X               'NA'             J
6   2   Y               A                M            Y               B                I
7   18  X               B                J            X               A                L
8   85  X               A                I            Y               B                M
```

To describe - I need to separate values in columns 4 and 5, put into new columns and give them the name according to the records in columns 3. There is different number of values separated by ":" in third column.

What should I do in order to spread values and stay the name of fourth and fifth columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `tidyverse` (which imports `tidyr` as well) you can use `separate`:

```
library(tidyverse)

new_df = df %>%
  separate('value_1', c('value_1_country', 'value_1_province', 'value_1_city'), sep = ":") %>%
  separate('value_2', c('value_2_country', 'value_2_province', 'value_2_city'), sep = ":")

new_df
```

The result I get from that step:

```
> new_df
  ID age         type_location value_1_country value_1_province value_1_city value_2_country value_2_province value_2_city
1  1  83 country:province:city               X                A            J               X                A            I
2  2  15          country:city               X                K         <NA>               X                J         <NA>
3  3   2 country:province:city               Y                B            I               Y                B            I
4  4  12          country:city               X                L         <NA>               Z                K         <NA>
5  5   2          country:city               Y                J         <NA>               X                J         <NA>
6  6   2 country:province:city               Y                A            M               Y                B            I
7  7  18 country:province:city               X                B            J               X                A            L
8  8  85 country:province:city               X                A            I               Y                B            M
```

For separate the first argument is your dataframe, the second is the column to separate, the third is the vector of column names, and `sep=''` is the character to separate by.

You can also specify NAN handling and stuff, see here:

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html

The other person got to the full answer faster so I'm not going to finish typing a full solution.

Comment: But the clue is to take the names from the third column and put into the name of new columns (and their number differ, so I can't build a fixed vector with names).

Comment: Ok, now I actually fixed my (several) typos and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure, there are more elegant ways than mine, but using dplyr/tidyverse you could do the following.

It's always considered polite to provide your data as output from `dput(df)`, because this can be read into R more easily.

```r
df=structure(list(ID = 1:8, 
                  age = c(83L, 15L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 85L), 
                  type_location = c("country:province:city", "country:city", 
                                    "country:province:city", "country:city",
                                    "country:city", "country:province:city", 
                                    "country:province:city", "country:province:city"),
                  value_1 = c("X:A:J","X:K", "Y:B:I", "X:L", "Y:J", "Y:A:M", "X:B:J", "X:A:I"), 
                  value_2 = c("X:A:I", "X:J", "Y:B:I", "Z:K", "X:J", "Y:B:I", "X:A:L", "Y:B:M")),
             class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

library(tidyverse)

df_sep=df %>% 
  separate(col=value_1,into=c(paste0("value_1_",c("country","province","city"))),sep=":",remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(value_1_city=ifelse(nchar(value_1)<4,value_1_province,value_1_city),
         value_1_province=ifelse(nchar(value_1)<4,NA,value_1_province)) %>% 
  separate(col=value_2,into=c(paste0("value_2_",c("country","province","city"))),sep=":",remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(value_2_city=ifelse(nchar(value_2)<4,value_2_province,value_2_city),
         value_2_province=ifelse(nchar(value_2)<4,NA,value_2_province))
```

I set `remove=FALSE` so you can check the output more easily. If you want to remove the original columns, just set `remove=T` (the default).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data.table approach (which can probably be shortened)...

```
library( data.table )

dt <- fread("ID  age type_location          value_1  value_2    
1   83  country:province:city  X:A:J    X:A:I
2   15  country:city           X:K      X:J
3   2   country:province:city  Y:B:I    Y:B:I
4   12  country:city           X:L      Z:K
5   2   country:city           Y:J      X:J
6   2   country:province:city  Y:A:M    Y:B:I
7   18  country:province:city  X:B:J    X:A:L
8   85  country:province:city  X:A:I    Y:B:M")

#get #types of location
z <- length(unique(unlist(strsplit(dt$type_location, ":"))))
#create new columns
dt[, paste0( "location_",1:z) := tstrsplit( type_location, ":" )]
dt[, paste0( "value_1_",1:z) := tstrsplit( value_1, ":" )]
dt[, paste0( "value_2_",1:z) := tstrsplit( value_2, ":" )]
#melt
ans <- melt( dt[, -(3:5)], 
             id.vars = c("ID", "age"), 
             measure.vars = patterns(location = "^location", 
                                     value_1 = "^value_1", 
                                     value_2 = "^value_2") )
#remove rows with NA
ans <- ans[ complete.cases(ans), ]
#cast to desired format
dcast(ans, ID + age ~ location, value.var = c("value_1", "value_2"))
```

**output**

```
#    ID age value_1_city value_1_country value_1_province value_2_city value_2_country value_2_province
# 1:  1  83            J               X                A            I               X                A
# 2:  2  15            K               X             <NA>            J               X             <NA>
# 3:  3   2            I               Y                B            I               Y                B
# 4:  4  12            L               X             <NA>            K               Z             <NA>
# 5:  5   2            J               Y             <NA>            J               X             <NA>
# 6:  6   2            M               Y                A            I               Y                B
# 7:  7  18            J               X                B            L               X                A
# 8:  8  85            I               X                A            M               Y                B
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course I would pick [Ryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58596493/6461462), but if one wants to avoid hard-coding names, this works.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 %>% 
  group_split(ID) %>% 
  map(., ~ separate_rows(.x, -c(ID, age))) %>% 
  map(., ~ mutate(.x, type_location2 = type_location, 
                      type_location1 = type_location, 
                      type_location = NULL)) %>% 
  map(., ~pivot_wider(.x, names_from = type_location1, values_from = value_1,
                      names_prefix = "V_1_")) %>% 
  map(., ~pivot_wider(.x, names_from = type_location2, values_from = value_2,
                      names_prefix = "V_2_")) %>% 
  map(., ~group_by(.x, ID, age) %>% summarise_all(., na.omit)) %>% 
  bind_rows()

# # A tibble: 8 x 8
# # Groups:   ID [8]
#      ID   age V_1_country V_1_province V_1_city V_2_country V_2_province V_2_city
#   <int> <int> <chr>       <chr>        <chr>    <chr>       <chr>        <chr>   
# 1     1    83 X           A            J        X           A            I       
# 2     2    15 X           NA           K        X           NA           J       
# 3     3     2 Y           B            I        Y           B            I       
# 4     4    12 X           NA           L        Z           NA           K       
# 5     5     2 Y           NA           J        X           NA           J       
# 6     6     2 Y           A            M        Y           B            I       
# 7     7    18 X           B            J        X           A            L       
# 8     8    85 X           A            I        Y           B            M
```

#### *Data:*

```
df1 <- read.table(text="ID  age type_location          value_1  value_2    
                        1   83  country:province:city  X:A:J    X:A:I
                        2   15  country:city           X:K      X:J
                        3   2   country:province:city  Y:B:I    Y:B:I
                        4   12  country:city           X:L      Z:K
                        5   2   country:city           Y:J      X:J
                        6   2   country:province:city  Y:A:M    Y:B:I
                        7   18  country:province:city  X:B:J    X:A:L
                        8   85  country:province:city  X:A:I    Y:B:M", 
                  header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```